# MapKit MKpolyline rendering very slow

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios, latitude-longitude

I'm in the process of developing my first native iOS app using Xamarin, I'm using MapKit and MKPolyline to outline a route along the coast of Ireland, however, the way I'm doing it is taking way too long to render approx 6.5mins when I launch the application in my simulator. I realize this is down to the fact that I am using approx 64,000 coordinates to trace out the route, I extracted these points from a gpx file so I realise there is probably a lot of unnecessary points.
The code I've been using to generate the poly line is as follows

```
MKPolyline CoastalOverlay = MKPolyline.FromCoordinates(
new CLLocationCoordinate2D[] {      
new CLLocationCoordinate2D(51.704497, -8.520959),  
/* 
/* More CoOrdinates here    
*/
});

map.AddOverlay(CoastalOverlay);
public override MKOverlayView GetViewForOverlay(MKMapView mapView,IMKOverlay overlay)
{
// return a view for the polyline
MKPolyline polyline = overlay as MKPolyline;
MKPolylineView polylineView = new MKPolylineView(polyline);
polylineView.StrokeColor = UIColor.Purple;
return polylineView;
}
```

I'm self-teaching myself so I've been sticking to the Xamarin demos and tutorials and I'm wondering is there a more efficient and faster way of doing this? I've tried researching some minimisation algorithms but I haven't found any that seem to work for what I'm trying to do. 
Any help would be greatly appreciated :)

The code I have developed at the moment is working and doing what I'd like it to the problem just is it's very slow

Comment: You are going to have to sub-sample that 64k list based upon the map zoom level and visible area.

Comment: 64k coordinates is a lot!

Comment: @Cheesebaron Yeah I realise that and a lot of them are redundant as there are many points along a straight(ish) line that could be removed however I don't know any way of doing this other than manually opening the data in the likes of JOSM and removing sections of points I see that are redundant but this will be very very tedious and take a long time.

Comment: Well you could filter the points. I.e. measure the distance between them and filter away points which are, say, more than 100 meters apart in distance or something like that.